# Series expansion of PolyLog[2, 1/z]

Tags: special-functions, series-expansion

There is a well known identity involving the Dilogarithm:
$$
\mathrm{Li}_2(1/z) = - \mathrm{Li}_2(z) - \frac{\pi^2}{6} - \frac{1}{2} \log^2(-z)
$$
As far as I understand it should be valid for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

It can be checked in Mathematica as

```
zero = PolyLog[2, 1/z] + PolyLog[2, z] + \[Pi]^2/6 + 1/2 Log[-z]^2
```

For instance one can plot for random complex or real values of $z$ and check it vanishes.

Doing series expansion seems to work for some cases

```
Normal @ Series[zero, {z, 0, 10}, Assumptions -> z<0] // Simplify
```

> 0

```
Normal @ Series[zero, {z, Infinity, 10}, Assumptions -> z>0] // Simplify
```

> 0

```
Normal @ Series[zero, {z, -Infinity, 10}, Assumptions -> z<0] // Simplify
```

> 0

but it does fail for positive $z$

```
Normal @ Series[zero, {z, 0, 10}, Assumptions -> z>0] // Simplify
```

> 2 I [Pi] Log[z]

Is this a bug or is it expected that this identity is not valid for $z > 0$? Then why numerical evaluation works just fine? I am using Mathematica 12.0.

Comment: Pretty sure that expression is valid outside  [0,1].  See Polylogarithm wikipedia article (inversion formula).

Comment: See: `Plot[Evaluate@
  ReIm[1/6 (\[Pi]^2 + 3 Log[-z]^2) + PolyLog[2, 1/z] + 
    PolyLog[2, z]], {z, -2, 2}, WorkingPrecision -> 20, 
 PlotLegends -> {"Re", "Im"}]`

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk: No output on my comp during approximately 15 minutes.

Comment: @user64494. Using `MMA 12.2.0` I have plot with about 1 sec.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk: I am also using 12.2 . Can you present that plot through e.g. Dropbox? TIA.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk: Don't trouble it, please. I got the plot on a fresh kernel.

Comment: Thanks Dominic and MariuszIwaniuk, you are absolutely right, it's not supposed to be valid for $0<z<1$. Should I just remove the post since it doesn't seem to add much?

Comment: The restriction you eventually noticed is actually mentioned in the [Wolfram Functions Site](https://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/PolyLog2/17/01/01/0003/). The version that is correct for all complex variables is [this one](https://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/PolyLog2/17/01/01/0004/).